# peek doesn't support some sequences

Tags: clojure

I encountered an error while using `peek` function with a seq object. This was a bit surprising for me because I was expecting that `peek` would work with any seq object.

```
(def r0 
  (re-seq #"\w+" "foo bar"))
(identity r0)
;; ("foo" "bar")

(peek r0)
; (err) Execution error (ClassCastException) at (REPL:1).

(peek '("foo" "bar"))
;; "foo"

(= r0 '("foo" "bar"))
;; true

(type r0)
;; clojure.lang.Cons

(type '("foo"))
;; clojure.lang.PersistentList
```

The [documentation of `peek`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/peek) says that `peek` accepts a collection object. But sequences are collections too, right? But it is not supported by `peek`. So, is this a documentation error then? Or am I missing something else?

Comment: Documentation mentions list, queue, or vector, not collections in general. Peek works on stack-like collections (`IPersistentStack`).

Comment: TIL to use `peek` instead of `last` for vectors.

Comment: In reading the documentation on collections and sequences I see that Maps Vectors Lists and Sets are Collections.  I would have expected peek to work on all Collections, however peek seems to require an IPersistentStack.

Answer (score 3):

`peek` works with "persistent types implementing `clojure.lang.IPersistentStack` (like `clojure.lang.Persistent*`)", according to tomby42, 8.2 years ago in the doc notes.

Answer (score 3):

Clojure's doc string for function `peek` in Clojure 1.10.1 (current as of this writing) is: "For a list or queue, same as first, for a vector, same as, but much
more efficient than, last. If the collection is empty, returns nil."

In some discussion of peek's documentation on Clojurians Slack, it sounds like perhaps the word "collection" in peek's doc string is referring to one of the earlier-mentioned collection types of list, queue, or vector, not arbitrary Clojure collections.  That is, it should be interpreted the same as if the word "collection" was replaced with the phrase "list, queue, or vector".